# Add a vertical scrollbar to enhanced grid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

How can we add a vertical scrollbar to enhanced grid. Is there any property by which we can set a scrollbar to the grid like

```
verticalSrcoll : true
```

I could not find any property doing the same.

Why I need this property because there is something weird happening here and I dont know how this is happening.

Problem is at first load I am loading 10 records in the grid but I am not able see all the 10 records in the grid. Only 5 records are visible and there is no scrollbar also for this. Only by doing sorting, pagination or any operation I am able to see all the records. Is this a defualt behaviour

Thats why I want a scrollbar so that even viewing in small screen(tablet) it be responsive.

Comment: Have you set width and height to the grid or the containerNode of the grid?

Comment: We have set width for grid by using intialWidth but height I am not sure how to set

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like `<div id="gridDiv"></div>` then you can use css

```
#gridDiv {
    height: 20em;
}
```

or a style property to the grid like

```
"style","height: 700px; width: 800px;"
```

or if you want to set it programmatically

```
this.yourGird.set("style","height: 700px; width: 800px;");
```

Comment: It is not working in IE...at first load...when we change page size or pagination button it will work

Comment: what could be reason for that?

Comment: before you resize check the height of the grid or the container node and the same after that. you might notice a change in the height. This will give you a clue